# Joomla 3 navigation incorrect .current class

Tags: html, class, joomla, navigation, joomla3.0

I am web developer and I found a strange issue on navigation bar. When I try to switch another page `.current` class stays on home page `<li>` but anything else is working perfectly. I copied all mod_menu core files in joomla folder but it didn't fixed the problem.

Any help?

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the second page is a child of the first, this is normal behavior.

Comment: No it is not a child, I added a screenshot, you can see it

Comment: And the two pages don't share an article?

Comment: No, Home page is a Single Article named "little about me" in different category, and this is a "category blog" named "news"

Comment: Strange. Here's a demo site. The problem doesn't occur. http://joomla30.cloudaccess.net/index.php/sample-sites

Comment: Have you looked at it in Firebug? Maybe Chrome just isn't showing you the updated classes for some reason. The menu in your screenshot doesn't seem to be applying .current to Home.

Comment: I installed a fresh joomla 3, The problem hasn't occurred yet. I still don't know why that happened

Comment: I had a similar problem, only it was with Heading tags. I checked everything, but could not figure out why H2 tags were in place of H1 tags - in the end same as you a fresh install of 3.0.1 worked...